# How to include numbering for references in bibliography alongwith formatting for last name, first name initial using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I am using the following code using `biblatex` package since I want last name followed by first name initials. However, the bibliography section isn't listed with numbers. So, I included the defer numbers and `resetnumbers=true` line in the code. However, I still don't get the numbered output in my bibliography section. Please help me out.

**CODE:**

```
\usepackage[%
    style=authortitle,
    citestyle=numeric,
    hyperref=true,
    giveninits=true,
    natbib=true,
    maxbibnames=99,
    uniquename=init,
    dashed=false, % re-print recurring author names in bibliography
    useprefix=true, % for inclusion of 'de' 'da' in surname
    urldate=long,
    sorting=none,
    backend=biber,
    defernumbers=true,  
]{biblatex} %uniquename=false...try


\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}  
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}  
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}  
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}  
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}  
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}  

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\nocite{*}  
\printbibliography[  
  heading=bibintoc,  
  title={Bibliography},  
  resetnumbers=true  
  ]
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

In short, I like my bibliography writing style, I just want it to be numbered.
In the `\usepackage`, if I insert `bibstyle=numeric`, then I get the numbering in the bibliography section but the formatting becomes first name initial followed by last name.

Comment: I'd change `style=authortitle, citestyle=numeric,` to `style=numeric` and add `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}`

Comment: For future reference, please note that the code as posted does not constitute an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). The TeX code is missing the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and we don't have your `bibliography.bib`. Just copy and paste the code into an empty `.tex` file in a new empty directory, compile it and observe what we see.

Comment: Thank you so much @moewe. The edit you suggested works. Thank you so much. I invested almost like 5 hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a numeric bibliography with inverted names, then I suggest you stick to `style=numeric` and don't load `authortitle` at all.

You then need to do what `authortitle` does with `sortname` manually.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  sorting=none,
  maxbibnames=99,
  giveninits=true,
  useprefix=true,
  defernumbers=true,
  urldate=long,
  natbib=true,]{biblatex}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,cicero}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E., Ryde, U. ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]